# How to export my R dataframes to excel? R

Tags: r, dplyr, datatables

This is a dataframe I have,

```
Sales <- data.frame(State  = c("New York", "New Jersey", "Texas","New Mexico","California",
                               "Kansas","Florida","Alaska","Montana", "Maine"),
                    
                    ManagerName = c("Chip","Kelly","Steve","Young","Troy",
                                    "Aikman", "Chad","Pennington","Mike","Vick"),
                    
                    May_Units = c(455,453,125,135,135,568,451,125,215,314),
                    
                    May_Sales = c("20000","12530","51110","54110","65000",
                                  "58220","54612","45102","45896","12510"),
                    
                    May_TargetSales = c("20000","20000","55000","50000","65000",
                                        "58000","55000","45000","45000","13000"),
                    
                    June_Units = c(855,153,225,335,135,438,351,325,115,614),
                    
                    June_Sales = c("40000","12330","41110","24110","35000",
                                   "18220","12612","44102","21896","23510"),
                    
                    June_TargetSales = c("25000","20000","65000","55000","65000",
                                        "20000","30000","45000","50000","20000")
                    
                    
)


write_xlsx(Sales, "Sales_by_state_May_June.xlsx")
```

When I export this dataframe to excel, is there a way to group the May Columns and June Columns? As well as add cell/font color, cell width/height in R? When I export them to excel using `write.xlsx()`, my data exports blank and I have to manually add the color and format cell width/heights.

For example, this would be my desired output... I need to create multiple of these tables so if I can do the table edits in R it would save me plenty of time. Can I also include the date and my name on the top row?

Is there any package that can let me do this custom table in R but output to excel? If you can post the package manual I can review it and make the edits to my code. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you'll find all the options in this package, but the openxlsx package provides a lot of options to change the look & feel of your desired Excel output. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.3

Comment: A workaround could be loading a preformatted excel with `openxlsx::loadWorkbook` and then write/update the data with `openxlsx::writeData`. This should work if your table has a fixed size.

Comment: @tspano How does that work? I can have a preset table and then open it with R and then load the data in there?

Comment: Basically yes, `writeData` will not touch the formatting